# My /proc/self/environ out of sudden is readable

Tags: linux

I was trying to get `/proc/self/environ` readable on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine for like forever but when I tried to change its permission to get it readable I get an `Operation not permitted`.

Now all of a sudden it's readable and I can see the output of `/proc/self/environ`.

How is it possible when I was trying to get it readable and I couldn't? Can someone please tell me how now get it unreadable and output nothing but a blank white page?

Comment: Why do you need it "unreadable and output nothing but a blank white page"? Please confirm there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. What made you believe it wasn't readable before? Do you know `proc` filesystem is special? Do you know the difference between `/proc/self` and `/proc/$N`? (where `$N` is any PID).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough when describing the problem. First of all No its not a XY problem. I know /proc/self/environ is readable through terminal but I couldn't get an output of /proc/self/environ through browser. I was actually happy to see it rather a white blank page. I know that its a special filesystem, which that is why I can't chmod it to anything. No I have no clue about the difference of /self and any PID. I shall read about that. What I would like to know is why Now /self/environ contents's got displayed on browser When like a month ago I couldn't. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps remove the nosuid option for the /proc filesystem? Or remount it w/o it?

This will remount it with the nosuid option

```
mount -o remount,nosuid,noexec /proc
```

Running mount again will confirm its in place.